# What is the correct way to make multiple objects?

Tags: python, grammar

I'm learning python and now I have hit a problem.

I have to make multiple objects, "store" them for later use, and then save the output into a file. My GUI interface is made in Qt4.

What I did so far is this:

```
class YamlPrepr:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.module = ""
        self.module_opt = ""
        self.condition = ""
        self.param = ""
        self.param_opt = ""

    def __repr__(self):
        s1 = "- name: %s" % self.name
        if (self.param and self.param_option) == "":
            s2 = "  %s: name=%s" % (self.module, self.module_opt)
        else:
            s2 = "  %s: name=%s" % (self.module, self.module_opt) + " %s=%s" % (self.param, self.param_option)
        return s1 + "\n" + s2


    def modulepak(self,line,line2):
        s = line.split(" ")[0]
        self.module = s
        self.module_opt = line2

    def parameter(self,line1,line2):
        self.param = line1
        self.param_opt = line2
```

I use the class like this:

```
def add_yaml(self):
    self.objects.append(self.module_name.displayText())
    self.mod = YamlPrepr(self.module_name.displayText())
    self.mod.modulepak(self.job_box.currentText(),self.option_line.displayText())
    if self.param_check.isChecked() == True:
        self.mod.parameter(self.param_box.currentText(),self.choice_line.displayText())
    self.display_line(self.mod.__repr__())
```

INFO:
`self.module_name.displayText()` is a QLineEdit, output is a string
`self.module_name.displayText()` is a QLineEdit, output is a string
`self.job_box.currentText()` is a QComboBox, output is a string
`self.param_box.currentText()` is a QComboBox, output is a string
`self.option_line.displayText()` is a QLineEdit, output is a string
`self.choice_line.displayText()` is a QLineEdit, output is a string

Every time I run this line `self.mod = YamlPrepr(self.module_name.displayText())` I believe the object is destroyed and initialize a new one. Am I right?

Is there a way to have multiple objects "alive" and add to them more `def parameter` or `def modulepak` no matter when, and when I 'm done to be able to save them into a file (txt or json)?

EX:

Object 1

- name (mariadb)
- parameter: status,force,update
- modulepak: apt

Object2

- name (httpd)
- parameter: status,update
- modulepak: yum

EDIT:
i'm adding the class where `add_yaml()` is called.

```
class YamlGenerator(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        file_path = os.path.abspath('ui/yaml.ui')
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.objects = []
        self.module_combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.check_module_name)
        self.job_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.show_params)
        self.module_btn.pressed.connect(self.add_module_index)
        self.condition_btn.pressed.connect(self.add_condition_index)
        self.add_mod_btn.pressed.connect(self.add_yaml)
        self.save_yaml.pressed.connect(self.save_temporary_to_file)
        self.check_module_name()

    def add_yaml(self):
        self.objects.append(self.module_name.displayText())
        self.mod = YamlPrepr(self.module_name.displayText())
        self.mod.modulepak(self.job_box.currentText(),self.option_line.displayText())
        if self.param_check.isChecked() == True:
            self.mod.parameter(self.param_box.currentText(),self.choice_line.displayText())
        self.display_line(self.mod.__repr__())
```

Comment: I am quite familiar with Qt in Python and C++, but I don't really get what you need? Do you get an Error? Or dou you just want to make sure you have multiple objects?

Comment: i just want more objects.

Comment: do you want the objects to be created dynamically at runtime?

Comment: not at runtime, `def add_yaml(self):` is running when I press a button. not when i start the app

Comment: Is `add_yaml()` a method of the `YamlPrepr` class? Regardless, everytime you do a `self.mod = YamlPrepr(self.module_name.displayText())` the previous value of `self.mod` is discarded. Maybe all you need to do it make `self.mod` a `list` of objects and then `append()` new `YamlPrepr` instances to it each time `add_yaml()` is called — like you're doing with `self.objects`.

Comment: `add_yaml()` is a member of another class called `class YamlGenerator(QtGui.QFrame):` and i run it from there.